# ADDRESS WIDTH from RAM DEPTH

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am implementing a configurable DPRAM where RAM DEPTH is the parameter.

How to determine ADDRESS WIDTH from RAM DEPTH?

I know the relation RAM DEPTH = 2 ^ (ADDRESS WIDTH)

i.e ADDRESS WIDTH = log (base 2) RAM DEPTH.

How to implement the log (base 2) function in Verilog?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `$clog2` system task was added to the SystemVerilog extension to Verilog (IEEE Std 1800-2005). This returns an integer which has the value of the ceiling of the log base 2.  The DEPTH need not be a power of 2.

```
module tb;

parameter DEPTH = 5;
parameter WIDTH = $clog2(DEPTH);

initial begin
    $display("d=%0d, w=%0d", DEPTH, WIDTH);
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Running a simulation will display this:

```
d=5, w=3
```

However, I do not know of a synthesis tool which supports `$clog2`.  If you need to synthesize your code, you can use a `function`.  This was copied from the IEEE 1364-2001 Std, but there are other versions floating around the web:

```
function integer clogb2;
    input [31:0] value;
    begin
        value = value - 1;
        for (clogb2 = 0; value > 0; clogb2 = clogb2 + 1) begin
            value = value >> 1;
        end
    end
endfunction
```

My experience has been that using the `function` is more trouble than it's worth for synthesizable code. It has caused problems for other tools in the design flow (linters, equivalence checkers, etc.).

Comment: Since it has been a few years since this answer was posted, I would like to point out that (at least some) synthesis tools do support $clog2 now. If your tool doesn't support it I would see if you can request it since it is a very useful function.

Comment: Verified that icestorm can synthesize `$clog2`.

Comment: recent Quartus versions support this. But i have seen issues with simulators like Incisive IUS.

Answer (score 25):

While $clog2 is the correct answer, until the tool vendors catch up, you can implement your own clog2 function as a verilog-2001 macro, which will work with all synthesis and simulation tools.

Such as:

```
`define CLOG2(x) \
   (x <= 2) ? 1 : \
   (x <= 4) ? 2 : \
   (x <= 8) ? 3 : \
   (x <= 16) ? 4 : \
   (x <= 32) ? 5 : \
   (x <= 64) ? 6 : \
   ..etc, as far as you need to go..
   (x <= 4294967296) ? 32 : \
   -1

parameter FOO_MAX_VALUE = 42;
parameter FOO_WIDTH = `CLOG2(FOO_MAX_VALUE);
```

Where the final "-1" is used to produce an illegal value the the simulator should flag.

(late edit: oops, fixed my off-by-one error!)

Comment: Subtle difference, your first version calculates the bit width; while your edit calculates the ceiling of log base 2. So both algorithms are useful. Perhaps you could edit your post to show them both, i.e. CLOG2(x) and BIT_WIDTH(x).