# Logarithm in Verilog

Tags: verilog, logarithm

I've a statement in verilog looking like `integer level = log(N)` (Where N is a parameter and level is to be determined) But I understand I cannot do complex math statements in verilog, so I'm wondering if there is an alternative solution to the above problem?

Any feedback appreciated!

Comment: What kind of logarithm are you trying to computer? An integer log base 2 is easy. A floating point log base e is much harder.

Comment: Is N a compile-time constant?

Comment: yes! Its a parameter to the module

Comment: In that case it's pretty easy. You can use a lookup table if N is small and speed is an issue. If N can get large, you can just loop over the bits of N from left to right, until you find a 1 bit.

Comment: how do you do a lookup table? Also N caps out at 128 or maybe 256 but thats about it

Comment: You can find an explanation and an implementation in SystemVerilog (quite similar to Verilog) of a Logarithm in base 2 in this website: http://sistenix.com/logarithm.html Once the log2 is simpler to be implemented compared to other bases, you can calculate other logarithms in different bases just multiplying the result of log2 by a constant number.

Comment: @Gabe would you please let me more how I can do this " If N can get large, you can just loop over the bits of N from left to right, until you find a 1 bit."?

Answer (score 11):

If it is a logarithm base 2 you are trying to do, you can use the built-in function `$clog2()`.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to [ADDRESS WIDTH from RAM DEPTH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269634/address-width-from-ram-depth) describes a couple ways to evaluate constant logarithms in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Verilog has functions for natural logarithm (`$ln()`), decadic logarithm (`$log10()`) and ceiling of binary logarithm (`$clog2()`). In constant expressions they should be synthesizable, but actual support by tools varies.

The following is synthesizable Verilog code:

```
module test(output [31:0] a, b, c);
  assign a = 1000 * $ln(123);
  assign b = 1000 * $log10(123);
  assign c = 1000 * $clog2(123);
endmodule
```

E.g. after RTL synthesis with [Yosys](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/) (e.g. `yosys -p 'prep; write_verilog -noattr' test.v`):

```
module test(a, b, c);
  output [31:0] a;
  output [31:0] b;
  output [31:0] c;
  assign a = 32'd4812;
  assign b = 32'd2090;
  assign c = 32'd7000;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

> But I understand I cannot do complex math statements in Verilog

Verilog is first and foremost a hardware description language. What hardware `log(N)` statement is describing? Modern FPGAs consist of LUTs, flops, small embedded memories, simple DSPs that implement MAC (multiply-accumulate) primitives. `log(N)` and other complex math statements cannot be mapped directly into those primitives. The same goes with ASICs.

By analogy, `log(N)` doesn't get executed by a processor. It calls a bunch of lower-level assembly instructions to do so. Those assembly instructions are part of the `log(N)` library (C, C++, etc.)

To be able to synthesize `log(N)` for ASIC/FPGA it requires an instance of a `log(N)` IP core.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of (logarithm base n of value) as answering the question "How many base n digits do I need to represent 'value' independent numbers?" (Keeping in mind that 0 counts as a number)

Thinking of it that way, you can implement your own log base 2 in SystemVerilog:

```
function bit [31:0] log_base_2 (bit [31:0] log_input);
  bit [31:0] input_copy;
  bit [31:0] log_out = 0;
  input_copy = log_input;

  while(input_copy > 0)begin
    input_copy = input_copy >> 1;
    log_out = log_out + 1;
  end
  log_out = log_out - 1;

  if(log_input != (1 << log_out))
    log_out = log_out + 1;

  return log_out;
endfunction
```