# Verilog Minimum Bit Width

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm looking for a clean way to declare Verilog/SystemVerilog types with a parameterised bit width. This is what I've got so far and was wondering if there is a better way to do it. I've looked through the system functions in the LRM 1800-2009 and -2017. The closest I could find is `$bits`, but I would like something like `$minbits`. Have I overlooked something?

In VHDL, it's done by simply specifying the `range`:

```vhdl
    signal counter: integer range 0 to MAX_COUNT;
```

...and the compiler will calculate the minimum bit width to hold that `range`.

For the parameter values of 20 ns and 125 ms, the counter should be 23 bits with MAX_COUNT being 6,250,000.

```c
module Debounce
#(
    parameter CLOCK_PERIOD_ns    = 20,  // nanoseconds.
    parameter DEBOUNCE_PERIOD_ms = 125  // milliseconds.
)
. . .
    function int MinBitWidth([1023:0] value);
        begin
            for (MinBitWidth = 0; value > 0; MinBitWidth = MinBitWidth + 1)
            begin
                value = value >> 1;
            end
        end
    endfunction

    localparam MAX_COUNT_32BITS = DEBOUNCE_PERIOD_ms * 1_000_000 / CLOCK_PERIOD_ns;  // Default type of 32-bits.

    localparam COUNTER_BITS = MinBitWidth(MAX_COUNT_32BITS);  // Calculate actual bit width needed.
    typedef logic [COUNTER_BITS - 1 : 0] TCounter;
    localparam TCounter MAX_COUNT = MAX_COUNT_32BITS;  // Assign to a type of the actual bit width (truncation warning from Quartus).
    localparam TCounter ONE = 1;
    TCounter counter;
. . .
    always @(posedge clock)
    begin
. . .
        if (counter == MAX_COUNT_32BITS - 1)  // Synthesises a 32-bit comparer no matter how many bits are needed with unused bits tied to ground.
. . .
        if (counter == MAX_COUNT - ONE)       // Synthesises a 23-bit comparer as expected.
. . .
            counter <= counter + 1;           // Synthesises a 23-bit counter as expected.
. . .
            counter <= counter + ONE;         // Synthesises a 23-bit counter as expected.
```

## Incorrect Algorithm

I considered `$clog2` which is [the correct way to obtain an ***address*** bus width from a RAM ***depth*** parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269634/address-width-from-ram-depth/). However, this is not the same as the ***minimum bit width*** of a value. Let me explain...

Consider a value of 4 which is 100 base-2 (3 bits wide).

The `$clog2` algorithm calculates a value of 2, which is incorrect. It should be 3. The reason for this miscalculation is because `$clog2` subtracts 1 from the value before it starts to compute the number of bits, i.e. 4 becomes 3, then it calculates the minimum bit width of the value 3, giving 2 bits. While this is *mathematically* correct for the *ceiling of log base-2*, it is **not** the *bit width* of the *original* value.

Here is the `clogb2` algorithm from the LRM:

```c
function integer clogb2;
    input [31:0] value;
    begin
        value = value - 1;  // GOTCHA!
        for (clogb2 = 0; value > 0; clogb2 = clogb2 + 1) begin
            value = value >> 1;
        end
    end
endfunction
```

## Correct Algorithm

The correct algorithm is to calculate the minimum bit width of the ***original*** value, which is the algorithm given by [@jonathan-mayer in his first answer before he edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737411/3344853).

Here is the correct algorithm as a function:

```c
function integer MinBitWidth;
    input [1023:0] value;
    begin
        for (MinBitWidth = 0; value > 0; MinBitWidth = MinBitWidth + 1)
        begin
            value = value >> 1;
        end
    end
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do +1 to get correct values for powers of 2.

`$clog2(MAX_COUNT_32BITS + 1);`

Comment: That's a great suggestion to fix the algorithm, but it kind of obfuscates the meaning of it from a semantic point of view. I could replace the body of the `MinBitWidth` function with `$clog2(value+1);` to keep the semantic meaning, but I'm also looking for a way to eliminate the rest of the awkward coding.

Comment: Set the count to +1.  This is the natural range, because it includes zero.  If the maximum value is 4, then you need space to support 5 values. [0 .. 4].  There is no 'un-naturalness' to this answer.  It is a fact of zero based numbers.  The define is semantically wrong.  It is MAX_COUNT_VALUE as '4' and MAX_COUNT_RANGE as '5'.

Answer (score 0):

`$clog2` from IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 20.8.1 *Integer math functions*:

> The system function `$clog2` shall return the ceiling of the log base 2
> of the argument (the log rounded up to an integer value).

```
module tb;

    parameter CLOCK_PERIOD_ns    =  20;  // nanoseconds.
    parameter DEBOUNCE_PERIOD_ms = 125;  // milliseconds.
    localparam MAX_COUNT_32BITS = DEBOUNCE_PERIOD_ms * 1_000_000 / CLOCK_PERIOD_ns;  // Default type of 32-bits.
    localparam COUNTER_BITS = $clog2(MAX_COUNT_32BITS);  // Calculate actual bit width needed.

initial begin
    $display("MAX_COUNT_32BITS = %0d, COUNTER_BITS = %0d", MAX_COUNT_32BITS, COUNTER_BITS);
end

endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
MAX_COUNT_32BITS = 6250000, COUNTER_BITS = 23
```

Comment: I considered that after reading your answer about ADDRESS BUS WITDH (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269634/address-width-from-ram-depth/)[here], but there is a very subtle (even crafty) reason why it won't work. I'll update my post to explain the difference between min bit width and address bus width.

Comment: I've updated it now to show how `$clog2` can't calculate the minimum bit width of powers of 2.

Comment: Yes, but it's awkward coding. I would like to know if Verilog/SystemVerilog has this algorithm built-in somewhere so that I can use much simpler code like VHDL.

Comment: @tim Since you know that $clog2 subtracts one and you don't want that is there a reason that you don't use $clog2(value + 1)?

Comment: That's a great suggestion to fix the algorithm within the function `MinBitWidth`, but I'm looking for a way to eliminate the rest of the awkward coding as well.